# Angular 2 + Node JS for backend and frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, model-view-controller

I am little confuse about how to implement this especially for routing, how i handle routing for backend and front end and how about i using source (css, html , js ) which it will be different between front and back. thank you.

Comment: you can implement both separately. Create api on different port using node and call from angular which will be running on another port

Comment: Learn Angular. By reading a book, and/or the official documentation. You'll then realize that it provides tooling, that it's meant to build single page apps that handle routing, and that your backend only needs to provide REST services, and doesn't need to handle routing, CSS and HTML. Also note that the current version of Angular is 5.x.

Comment: how about handle backend interface, should it be in one routing with frontend..  ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that can be achieved using MEAN stack application.

Mean stack tutorial guide [Click here](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a0673c880aca7739224ee21/mean-stack-angular-5-crud-web-application-example) !!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Choose `Angular As your front End Framework to work with user-Interaction` that will be user seeing in his/her browser and `Node.Js for Backend Interaction to your Angular Application for making API calls` and fetching Data that you want not to be shared with users.

In regarding to routing question use Angular Router module that will handle how user move from one component to anthers on your Front-end.

In Back-end you can use Express router module to Handle your routing requests to specific urls.

Comment: how about admin panel ? i have a plan to use adminLTE which mean we need some different routing group

Comment: Routing is something you define according to your need. You can use AdminLTE just you need to do some changes as per your app flow.

Comment: thanks for your help, but can you give me more desc about app flow ? it better use single core angular or better split

Comment: I don,t get what you want to know but FYI angular is used to create Single Page Application (SPA) and it achieve it via routing that made different component to load as per our need without reloading page.It just load new components.

Comment: You Better go with some easy Tuts on routing [link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/overview/) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular 2 as Frontend and Node js as your backend.
Furthermore, the routing will be set on frontend to show html pages and to get the data or perform any sql operation or to put your logic you can use node js by creating methods and then calling these methods from angular 2.